# Machine learning. What is the advantage of using a single layered artificial neural network (as opposed to a multi-layered)?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

had exam today in Machine learning and I am unsure about a question.
What of the following alternatives would you guys select?

Question:
 What is the advantage of using a single layered artificial neural network (as opposed to a multi-layered)?

- a) Learning is faster
- b) All input variables are independent
- c) Arbitrarily complex decisions can be learned
- d) Less restriction bias

only one alternative is correct.

Comment: Which do you think is correct and why? ;)

Comment: its `e` all of the above!

Comment: well it cant be in my opinion b c cuz they are typically for multi-layered networks. More nods you have it can take more complex decisions and I know that in multil-layered the input values is independent. The neuron learns from its output and iterate through i singel layered is much shorter then in a multi-layered where it can be many iterations and you uses backpropagation so I chose a. for d I have no ide actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually find this quite interesting question, I do not understand the downvotes (and no close votes - which would be reasonable if someone thinks it is out-of-the-scope).

- Learning is faster - **rather true**, in one layer neural network we have simplier function model, less parameters, so it should converge faster. Even though, I would say **rather** true because for very specific data it may be actually the other way around - everything depends on the initialization, processing etc.
- All input variables are independent - independent on what? This answer seems weird, this is not a feature of the model, but the data based one, so in case of this particular test - also **false**
- Arbitrary complex decisions can be learned - **false** for both one and multi layer neural network unless we have more assumptions (at least 2 layers, continuous, differentable, nonlear activation functions, arbitrary number of hidden units, existance of bias)
- Less restriction bias - **false**, restriction bias is a restriction made on the classes of models searched. In case of one layer NN we restrict to linear classifiers (more or less, depending on usage of activation functions/kernelization), which is a very small subset of possible models (much narrower then the one avaliable in the MLP)

Comment: I think b) is referring to the model being linear in the input variables, i.e. of the form w.x. Or perhaps it should say "input variables are *assumed* to be independent", which is obviously false since NNs (and discriminative methods in general) make no assumptions about the input data. In any case, the wording is horrible: was this translated from another language?

Comment: I also dont understand why people downvotes but I got result today and the right answer was a) Learning is faster.